# Deploy Shiny application with older version of particular package

Tags: deployment, shiny, version, r-lavaan

This may be a stupid question, but I'm unable to solve the following issue:

I'm working on a Shiny-app and need an older version of *lavaan* to obtain the same results as a few weeks ago. I used the following code to install the older version locally: `install_version("lavaan",version = "0.5-23.1097")`, and I loaded this old version using `library(lavaan)` into my *server.R* file. I also added all possible dependencies to my list in the *server.R* file so that everything works fine locally.

However, when I try to deploy my application, I obtain the following at the end of my task log:

```
[2018-08-16T17:00:24.569989191+0000] Installing R package: quadprog (1.5-5)
* installing to library �/opt/R/3.4.0/lib/R/library�
* installing *binary* package �quadprog� ...
* DONE (quadprog)
[2018-08-16T17:00:24.749745586+0000] Building R package: lavaan (0.5-23.1097)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library �/opt/R/3.4.0/lib/R/library�
* installing *source* package �lavaan� ...
** package �lavaan� successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): 
    unable to load shared object '/opt/R/3.4.0/lib/R/library/quadprog/libs/quadprog.so':
    libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package �lavaan�
* removing �/opt/R/3.4.0/lib/R/library/lavaan�
```

Apparently, it is able to find the old lavaan version and unpack it, but as soon as it performs this `lazy loading` action, it breaks down.

Does anybody know where I could eliminate this `lazy loading` or perhaps where to find this `quadprog.so` or `libRblas.so` file? I assume that something more essential is going on, but I can't figure it out. Below, you can find my `sessionInfo()` output.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252 LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lavaan_0.5-23.1097 quadprog_1.5-5     MASS_7.3-47        numDeriv_2016.8-1  htmlwidgets_1.0    jsonlite_1.5       htmltools_0.3.6   
 [8] yaml_2.2.0         tibble_1.4.2       DT_0.2             ggplot2_2.2.1      rmarkdown_1.8      stringi_1.1.7      foreign_0.8-67    
 [15] magrittr_1.5       rsconnect_0.8.5    shinyjs_0.9.1      shinythemes_1.1.1  shiny_1.1.0        devtools_1.13.6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.18     git2r_0.18.0     pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.4.0   later_0.7.3      plyr_1.8.4       bitops_1.0-6     tools_3.4.0     
[9] digest_0.6.12    memoise_1.1.0    evaluate_0.10.1  gtable_0.2.0     rlang_0.2.1      rstudioapi_0.6   curl_3.1         pbivnorm_0.6.0  
[17] httr_1.2.1       withr_1.0.2      stringr_1.2.0    knitr_1.17       stats4_3.4.0     rprojroot_1.2    grid_3.4.0       R6_2.2.2        
[25] RJSONIO_1.3-0    backports_1.1.0  scales_0.4.1     promises_1.0.1   mnormt_1.5-5     mime_0.5         xtable_1.8-2     colorspace_1.3-2
[33] httpuv_1.4.5     miniUI_0.1.1     RCurl_1.95-4.8   lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    crayon_1.3.4
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my issue had nothing to do with managing package versions.
The solution can be found on this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/B08vBkeYg8w), thanks to Joshua Spiewak.

The gist is that the package `quadprog` was improperly compiled, although it was successfully installed. Flushing the package from the cache for R 3.4.0 solved the issue.

Thank you all for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using packrat to manage you package versions. This is how I run shiny apps with different versions of packages and it makes them deployable to connect servers in a way that maintains the correct package.

Comment: Hi Adam! 
Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'm trying out `packrat` at this very moment, based on this [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216528108-Deploying-packrat-projects-to-Shiny-Server-Pro), but I still got the errors. How exactly do you tell shiny to use the _packrat libraries_ when deploying the app using `rsconnect` (`deployApp` seems to ignore the `packrat` folder)?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: rsconnects deployment will automatically package this for you. can you post the output of rsconnect::appDependencies(). I am interested to see if rsconnect is pulling the wrong version dependency.

Comment: Hi Adam. If `rsconnect` deploys the libraries mentioned in `packrat`, I suspect these versions of the dependencies will be used when deploying. (I had some trouble initiating `packrat` for this reason: as some versions of the dependencies needed to be _older_). However, the same error keeps popping up when deploying, even using `packrat`. Do you have any idea how this can be resolved?